MacOs Sonoma ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Namans-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)
On Mac OS X v14.4 (Sonoma),
starting MySQL gives the following error:
Command - mysql.server start
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/s-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)

Error found in log file /usr/local/var/mysql/s-MacBook-Pro.local.err
2024-05-08T04:00:40.205586Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.205601Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.297396Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012526] [InnoDB] Upgrade is not supported after a crash or shutdown with innodb_fast_shutdown = 2. This redo log was created with MySQL 5.7.43, and it appears logically non empty. Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/upgrading.html
2024-05-08T04:00:40.297429Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.297916Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.298302Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.298322Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-05-08T04:00:40.299674Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.3.0_1/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.3.0)  Homebrew.
2024-05-08T04:00:40.299680Z 0 [System] [MY-015016] [Server] MySQL Server - end.

